# Can't find text file

Tags: c#, xna, stream, .net

I'm trying to read some ints from a textfile in my XNA game. Now when I try this method in a console app it works just fine.

However when I try this in my XNA game i get the following error:

```
 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Version01\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\bin\x86\Debug\positions.txt'.'
```

First for the obvious... lol yes the file is in the debug folder.

```
   public void ReadPositions(string path)
     {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < PositionList.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector2 placeHolder;
                placeHolder.X = float.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                placeHolder.Y = float.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                PositionList[i] = placeHolder;

            }

        }
    }
```

And when I call it :

```
 ReadPositions("positions.txt");
```

Any suggestions as to why it isn't being found? I'm a beginner so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using underscores instead of spaces in your file path. Programming doesn't like spaces. 
Visual Studio 2010, though made by visual studio, may actually need to be Visual_Studio_2010.

Comment: My file path is "positions.txt"

Comment: C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Version01\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\bin\x86\Debug\positions.txt

instead try:

C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Visual_Studio_2010\Projects\Version01\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\V1SpaceKillers\bin\x86\Debug\positions.txt'.'

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to input that as the path so long as the file is in the solutions bin folder. For example I save and load in this game (which works fine) and the path for that is: SaveGame("SaveData.txt"), which reads and writes fine?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you actually have three folders called V1SpaceKillers?

Comment: Haha! Just found the problem. The stream was looking in an older directory lol..., Yeah I should work on not block copying my projects when I create a new version. Cheers for the answer :)

Comment: if I helped at all, please don't forget to mark it, otherwise, make sure you close the thread as answered

Comment: Not a problem, I have issues with directory names a lot, so it's the first thing a check. I'm glad I could help!